# SQL Server: Business Intelligence Development Studio

Tags: reporting-services, bids

I apologise in advance as I appreciate my question is a generic one, rather than focusng on a specific issue.  After several days of hitting my head against a brick wall trying to learn SQL Server Reporting Services I have made little progress.

I have:

Built a SQL database

Built a client application in C# to access and work with that SQL database

And learnt how to design reports in Business Intelligance Development Studio based on the data in the SQL database

What I can't do:

Is deploy my reports so that these can be accessed in any way other than through the Business Intelligence Development Studio.

Each time I select Deploy I am asked for credentials - and no matter what details I use (my Windows credentials) or the 'sa' account created on SQL Server installation - I simply cannot deploy my reports or access the SQL Server Reporting Services.

I've read multiple manuals - that I have purchased, and online, and I just can't figure this out.

Can anyone afford some advice - please!

Comment: In the 'Site Settings' section of the 'Reporting Services Configuration Manager' have you added yourself as 'System Administrator'?

Comment: Where is Site Settings please?  I can't see this in the configuration manager.

Comment: In the configuration manager look at report manager URL.  Go that URL in the upper right hand corner is 'Site Settings'.

Comment: I'm afraid that both the Web Service URL and the Report Manager URL are inaccessible because they both ask me for Credentials.  I'm working on my own local machine, I've never set up any passwords, I just don't know what these Credentials are?!

Comment: Is your account a member of the ReportServerUsers$... group in the Windows security groups?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up on SSRS in the end and opted for Crystal Reports which seems to have no such issues connecting to my database for getting its data.